# An error happened during template parsing (template: "ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/views/hello_world.html]") (Spring MVC + Thymleaf)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Вот контроллер

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @GetMapping("/hello-world")
    public String sayHello(){
        return "hello-world";
    }
}
```

Вот класс конфигурации контекста

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.rusned.mvc")
@EnableWebMvc
public class SpringConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    public SpringConfig(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        //templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        return templateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        templateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        registry.viewResolver(resolver);
    }

}
```

И html файл

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
Hello world
</body>
</html>
```

Плюс ко всему идея подсвечивает название html файла, т.е. просто не видит его
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я думаю это связано с проблемой.

Comment: может проблема в том, что у вас HTML называется как `hello_world`, а возвращаете как `hello-world`? То есть разница дефис и нижнее подчеркивание

Answer (score 0):

Как заметил @Chubatiy вам надо разобраться с именем файла. Ошибка Thymeleaf для файла "hello_world.html", но не видит ваш файл потому что в конфигурации у вас суфикс ".jsp", а надо ".html" ...

```
templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
```

`TemplateMode` почему-то закоментирован, это правильная конфигурация, оставьте её. И добавьте `characterEncoding` `UTF8`, потому что вы прописали это в вашем HTML.